# error:i/o operation on closed file while using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to train a neural network using data from a CSV file, my code it below. It pulls the data from the CSV, stores it in a list, converts this list to an array, and then uses two arrays as the x and y values to train the neural network.

```html
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import csv
from collections import defaultdict


columns = defaultdict(list) # each value in each column is appended to a list

                                 
    # Declare list of features, we only have one real-valued feature
def model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    with open('C:\\Users\\joe\\Documents\\EURUSD learn.txt') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f) # read rows into a dictionary format
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
        for (k,v) in row.items(): # go over each column name and value 
            columns[k].append(v) # append the value into the appropriate list
                                 # based on column name k
    openarray = np.asarray('<OPEN>')
    closearray = np.asarray('<CLOSE>')
    higharray = np.asarray('<HIGH>')
    lowarray = np.asarray('<LOW>')
    # Build a linear model and predict values
    W = tf.get_variable("W", [1], dtype=tf.float64)
    b = tf.get_variable("b", [1], dtype=tf.float64)
    y = W*features['x'] + b
    # Loss sub-graph
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(y - labels))
    # Training sub-graph
    global_step = tf.train.get_global_step()
    optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
    train = tf.group(optimizer.minimize(loss),
                 tf.assign_add(global_step, 1))
    # EstimatorSpec connects subgraphs we built to the
    # appropriate functionality.
    return tf.estimator.EstimatorSpec(
        mode=mode,
        predictions=y,
        loss=loss,
        train_op=train)

with open('C:\\Users\\joe\\Documents\\EURUSD learn.txt') as f:
    estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn=model_fn)
    # define our data sets
    x_train = np.array(['openarray'])
    y_train = np.array(['closearray'])
    x_eval = np.array(['higharray'])
    y_eval = np.array(['lowarray'])
    input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=None, shuffle=True)
    train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_train}, y_train, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)
    eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
    {"x": x_eval}, y_eval, batch_size=4, num_epochs=1000, shuffle=False)
    # train
    estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
    # Here we evaluate how well our model did.
    train_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=train_input_fn)
    eval_metrics = estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
    print("train metrics: %r"% train_metrics)
    print("eval metrics: %r"% eval_metrics)
```

When I run the code, I get the following error:

```html
WARNING:tensorflow:Using temporary folder as model directory: C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp3yj2dh4d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\stocks closing+opening.py", line 54, in <module>
    estimator.train(input_fn=input_fn, steps=1000)
  File "C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 302, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 711, in _train_model
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 694, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\stocks closing+opening.py", line 14, in model_fn
    for row in reader: # read a row as {column1: value1, column2: value2,...}
  File "C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\csv.py", line 109, in __next__
    self.fieldnames
  File "C:\Users\joe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\csv.py", line 96, in fieldnames
    self._fieldnames = next(self.reader)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

I looked up this error, and it seems to be that it is tying to run on a closed file, but I have the file open. Is this because I am using a temporary folder as a model directory?

Answer (score 0):

In your function *model_fn* you are opening the file using the *with* statement and you create a reader with that file. Then you are iterating over that reader, but the *for* is tabulated at the same level as the *with*, so when the reader tries to get the first line, the file is already closed because the *with* has ended.

Just try to put the for loop inside the with.